# Cannot use copy and paste while copying file from remote server

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, file-transfer, copy-paste, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using Windows Remote Desktop Connection to connect a remote server. 
My local machine runs Windows 8.1 and the server is Windows Server 2012 R2. 
If I copy a file from the server to my machine and during the copy I try to copy and paste anything on my local machine, the copying from the server to my machine is stopped with an error message. 
What is this problem and how can I solve it?

Error Message:

> ­    Error Copying File or Folder
>
> ---
>
> Unspecified Error

[image: error window (text shown above)]

In RDP options:

- "Local Resources" (tab) → "Local Devices and Resources" →
  "Clipboard" is checked.
- "Other" → "Drives" was not checked. 
  I checked them (it?) and unfortunately nothing changed.

I do not use any clipboard extender.

Comment: what is the error message? and just to check, in the RDP options on the "Local Resources" tab is Clipboard checked under "Local Devices and Resources"?

Answer (score 2):

I might be you have not checked the Clipboard option in the RDP options on the "Local Resources" tab under "Local Devices and Resources".

Comment: Sorry I go to add the error message and forget to see the other part of your comment.. back to you after minutes

Comment: Okay. Sorry, I misunderstood it that is working now :)

Comment: It was checked. It seems another problem

Comment: I had problems when using a clipboard extender on the local machine. Can you check and disable if any found? And if you click on "Other" on the same options page you can check if "Drives" is checked to see if you will be able to copy from the remotely connected drives on you local machine.

Comment: It was not checked. I checked them and unfortunately it did not change anything. and not I do not use any clipboard extender. Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you check the following on your W2012 Server: Open “Server Manager“.
Select “Remote Desktop” Services.
Select “Collections“.
Select “Tasks“, then choose “Edit Properties“.
Under the “Client Settings” tab, ensure the “Clipboard” and “Drive” is enabled.